# How do you extend an image out of a grid container to the edge of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-grid

I am having an issue with the background image inside of grid layout. Currently the background-image stays inside of the container as seen here:

[image: inside-container]

However I would like the image to extend out to the left to the edge of the viewport like so:

[image: extend-to-edge]

I cant seem to figure out how to do this. Here is my code so far:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1 {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1,
.flex-tier .grid-col-2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container#grid-tier {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-tier" class="flex-tier container ">
  <div class="grid-col-1">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec pulvinar turpis. Donec nec enim ultricies, ultrices libero ac, tincidunt nibh. In varius neque eu orci consequat, id vestibulum ex congue. Aliquam nulla sem, fermentum eget efficitur
        nec, gravida at risus. Phasellus molestie sit amet mauris interdum dapibus. Duis vehicula nulla sit amet dignissim tincidunt. Fusce pulvinar, magna sollicitudin sollicitudin pharetra, augue urna varius ex, a ullamcorper elit ante vehicula urna.
        Pellentesque aliquet posuere neque sed sodales. Nulla auctor magna eget nisi pulvinar sagittis. In a massa at tortor faucibus accumsan at eget nisl. Aliquam accumsan convallis ex et viverra. Pellentesque tempor turpis mi, sit amet tincidunt eros
        mattis et. Nullam sed ex non risus pulvinar euismod ut quis turpis. Proin ut vestibulum nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-col-2">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec pulvinar turpis. Donec nec enim ultricies, ultrices libero ac, tincidunt nibh. In varius neque eu orci consequat, id vestibulum ex congue. Aliquam nulla sem, fermentum eget efficitur
        nec, gravida at risus. Phasellus molestie sit amet mauris interdum dapibus. Duis vehicula nulla sit amet dignissim tincidunt. Fusce pulvinar, magna sollicitudin sollicitudin pharetra, augue urna varius ex, a ullamcorper elit ante vehicula urna.
        Pellentesque aliquet posuere neque sed sodales. Nulla auctor magna eget nisi pulvinar sagittis. In a massa at tortor faucibus accumsan at eget nisl. Aliquam accumsan convallis ex et viverra. Pellentesque tempor turpis mi, sit amet tincidunt eros
        mattis et. Nullam sed ex non risus pulvinar euismod ut quis turpis. Proin ut vestibulum nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertdg96/25Labsqr/12/) with my code as well. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your container is set at `max-width:1200px;` .
- backgrounds from children are not suppose to show outside the parent nor themselves.
- You also add `overflow:hidden;` to the child where background is suppose to show across the edge of the container to the left side of the viewport.

there is no way it will happen, your code works perfectly.

---

You may use an `absolute` pseudo from that child and size it from coordonates `top`,`right`,`bottom` and try to set the coordonates for `left` via `calc()` to match about to the left edge of the viewport.

the coding idea is :

```
.flex-tier .grid-col-1 {
  position: relative;/* to be reference for absolute children and pseudos */
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 60vw + 20px );/* where is the left edge about ? 
             start from the right (left:100% is equal to right:0 
             remove 60vw of the viewport that is the 60% ratio of your column at the minimum
             add your average margin */
  background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

below a working demo or the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25Labsqr/40/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:solid;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1 {
  position: relative;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 60vw + 20px );
  background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1,
.flex-tier .grid-col-2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container#grid-tier {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}


below, the working demo or a [fiddle][1]
```

```html
<div id="grid-tier" class="flex-tier container ">
  <div class="grid-col-1">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec pulvinar turpis. Donec nec enim ultricies, ultrices libero ac, tincidunt nibh. In varius neque eu orci consequat, id vestibulum ex congue. Aliquam nulla sem, fermentum eget efficitur
        nec, gravida at risus. Phasellus molestie sit amet mauris interdum dapibus. Duis vehicula nulla sit amet dignissim tincidunt. Fusce pulvinar, magna sollicitudin sollicitudin pharetra, augue urna varius ex, a ullamcorper elit ante vehicula urna.
        Pellentesque aliquet posuere neque sed sodales. Nulla auctor magna eget nisi pulvinar sagittis. In a massa at tortor faucibus accumsan at eget nisl. Aliquam accumsan convallis ex et viverra. Pellentesque tempor turpis mi, sit amet tincidunt eros
        mattis et. Nullam sed ex non risus pulvinar euismod ut quis turpis. Proin ut vestibulum nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-col-2">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec pulvinar turpis. Donec nec enim ultricies, ultrices libero ac, tincidunt nibh. In varius neque eu orci consequat, id vestibulum ex congue. Aliquam nulla sem, fermentum eget efficitur
        nec, gravida at risus. Phasellus molestie sit amet mauris interdum dapibus. Duis vehicula nulla sit amet dignissim tincidunt. Fusce pulvinar, magna sollicitudin sollicitudin pharetra, augue urna varius ex, a ullamcorper elit ante vehicula urna.
        Pellentesque aliquet posuere neque sed sodales. Nulla auctor magna eget nisi pulvinar sagittis. In a massa at tortor faucibus accumsan at eget nisl. Aliquam accumsan convallis ex et viverra. Pellentesque tempor turpis mi, sit amet tincidunt eros
        mattis et. Nullam sed ex non risus pulvinar euismod ut quis turpis. Proin ut vestibulum nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another container for the image

```
<div id="image60"></div>
<div id="grid-tier" class="flex-tier container ">
  <div class="grid-col-1">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec pulvinar turpis. Donec nec enim ultricies, ultrices libero ac, tincidunt nibh. In varius neque eu orci consequat, id vestibulum ex congue. Aliquam nulla sem, fermentum eget efficitur
        nec, gravida at risus. Phasellus molestie sit amet mauris interdum dapibus. Duis vehicula nulla sit amet dignissim tincidunt. Fusce pulvinar, magna sollicitudin sollicitudin pharetra, augue urna varius ex, a ullamcorper elit ante vehicula urna.
        Pellentesque aliquet posuere neque sed sodales. Nulla auctor magna eget nisi pulvinar sagittis. In a massa at tortor faucibus accumsan at eget nisl. Aliquam accumsan convallis ex et viverra. Pellentesque tempor turpis mi, sit amet tincidunt eros
        mattis et. Nullam sed ex non risus pulvinar euismod ut quis turpis. Proin ut vestibulum nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-col-2">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec pulvinar turpis. Donec nec enim ultricies, ultrices libero ac, tincidunt nibh. In varius neque eu orci consequat, id vestibulum ex congue. Aliquam nulla sem, fermentum eget efficitur
        nec, gravida at risus. Phasellus molestie sit amet mauris interdum dapibus. Duis vehicula nulla sit amet dignissim tincidunt. Fusce pulvinar, magna sollicitudin sollicitudin pharetra, augue urna varius ex, a ullamcorper elit ante vehicula urna.
        Pellentesque aliquet posuere neque sed sodales. Nulla auctor magna eget nisi pulvinar sagittis. In a massa at tortor faucibus accumsan at eget nisl. Aliquam accumsan convallis ex et viverra. Pellentesque tempor turpis mi, sit amet tincidunt eros
        mattis et. Nullam sed ex non risus pulvinar euismod ut quis turpis. Proin ut vestibulum nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#image60 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1 {
  position: relative;
  /*  background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-tier .grid-col-1,
.flex-tier .grid-col-2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container#grid-tier {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
```

check it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nowak2009/25Labsqr/18/)